# Using an Environment Variable in Lieu of a File in a Command Argument

Tags: command-line, args

I'm using openssl for signing and verification of some binaries, and it requires some files to execute the command.

`openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public.pem -signature /tmp/sign.sha256 bin/the_file`

I'd love to pass in `public.pem` from an environment variable (obviously it's trivial to write this out to a file and then read that in, but it feels like an unnecessary step).

I *think* you can use xargs to do this? But I can never figure out how.